# Acumatica - Field Verifying on ContractID

Tags: acumatica

How do I reference the project ID in an Expense Receipt, to validate the value before it is saved? I would like to block use of the non-project code.

When I attempt to publish the code below, I receive the error:

```
\App_RuntimeCode\ExpenseClaimDetailEntry.cs(31): error CS0426: The type name 'ContractID' does not exist in the type 'ExpenseClaimDetailEntry'
```

The code that produces the error:

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldVerifying<ExpenseClaimDetailEntry.ContractID> e) //<-- Line 31
{
  if (e != null)
  {
    if ((string?)e.NewValue == "XXXXXXXX");
    {
      throw new PXSetPropertyException("Non-Project Code XXXXXXXX  cannot be used in expense reciepts.");
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:** This is my solution. Remove the default value using `e.NewValue = null` and `e.Cancel = true`, then block selection of the non-project code using `PXSetPropertyException`. YMMV.

```
protected void EPExpenseClaimDetails_contractID_FieldDefaulting(
    PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
  e.NewValue = null;
  e.Cancel = true; //Skip the standard FieldDefaulting code - It will revert ContractId to zero again!
}

protected void EPExpenseClaimDetails_contractID_FieldVerifying(Events.FieldVerifying<EPExpenseClaimDetails.contractID> e)
{
  if ((int?)e.NewValue == 0)
  {
    throw new PXSetPropertyException("Error: Project 'X' not allowed in expense reciepts.", PXErrorLevel.Error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each DAC field, there are **two variables** declared.

**1** There is a property (**C**ontractID). By convention the property starts with a upper-case letter:

```
[ProjectDefault("EA", AccountType = typeof(expenseAccountID))]
[PXDBInt]
[PXDimensionSelector("CONTRACT", typeof(Search2<Contract.contractID, LeftJoin<EPEmployeeContract, On<EPEmployeeContract.contractID, Equal<Contract.contractID>, And<EPEmployeeContract.employeeID, Equal<Current2<employeeID>>>>>, Where<Contract.isActive, Equal<True>, And<Contract.isCompleted, Equal<False>, And<Where<Contract.nonProject, Equal<True>, Or2<Where<Contract.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.contract>, And<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.contractManagement>>>, Or<Contract.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.project>, And2<Where<Contract.visibleInEA, Equal<True>>, And2<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.projectModule>, And2<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>, And<Where<Contract.restrictToEmployeeList, Equal<False>, Or<EPEmployeeContract.employeeID, IsNotNull>>>>>>>>>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<Contract.contractCD>>>), typeof(Contract.contractCD), new[] { typeof(Contract.contractCD), typeof(Contract.description), typeof(Contract.customerID), typeof(Contract.status) }, Filterable = true, ValidComboRequired = true, CacheGlobal = true, DescriptionField = typeof(Contract.description))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Project/Contract")]
public virtual int? ContractID { get; set; }
```

The property is used when you want to get or set the value of the field.

**2** The other variable is an abstract class (**c**ontractID). By convention it starts with lower-case letter:

```
public abstract class contractID : BqlType<IBqlInt, int>.Field<contractID>
```

The abstract class is used when you refer to a field as a pointer. It identifies a field but doesn't hold a value.

---

In your example you are declaring an event handler. For this you need to use the abstract class because the event points to the field instead of getting/setting the field value. Change '**C**ontractID' to '**c**ontractID':

```
void _(Events.FieldVerifying<ExpenseClaimDetail.contractID> e)
```

There's a second error, the class `EPExpenseClaimDetailsEntry` is a graph, not a DAC. Fields are in DAC (data access class) not in graph. So you have to use the DAC `EPExpenseClaimDetails` instead of the graph `EPExpenseClaimDetailsEntry` for the event handler generic type.

Comment: When saving the expense receipt, the result is "XXXXXXXX" for the project field. Do you know what would cause this?

Comment: That is the value that the user entered?

Comment: Since you use PXSetPropertyException to show error you might want to add RaiseExceptionHandling.

Comment: Finally got it - the non-project code ID is not a string, it is zero!